# Onmouse hover effect with text description

Tags: javascript, html, css, preloader

I am setting up my first website, and I want to add one functionality. I mean **onmouse effect**, when mouse is over an image - it's displaying details of image, but not as a hover effect on the image, but a new block next to the mouse.

This website is develop using Django as a backend part, and bootstrap with javascript on frontend part. I was already looking for any solution, but I couldn't find anything useful.

I am especially looking for some **hints**, or some examples which might lead me into expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS Animations, and `+` css selector to match a sibling `<p>`.
Here is an example:

```js
function imgHover(obj, event) {
  let span = obj.querySelector('span');
  span.style.left = event.offsetX + 'px';
  span.style.top = event.offsetY + 'px';
}
```

```css
.img-desc {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-desc span {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.img-desc:hover > span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-desc" onmousemove="imgHover(this, event)">
  <img width="240" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/536/354" />
  <span>Image description</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks great, and I will try to play with this for my need, but it's not actually what I was thinking of descibing question. I was thinking of this `<p>Image description</p>` as a content which show up next to the mouse when it's over the image, you think it's also possible with that ?

Comment: @mmalak do you want the text to follow the mouse? while mouse is moving?

Comment: Yes, that's actually something I was looking for

Comment: @mmalak I've just fixed the answer to do what you expected. Now it need some JS to handle the mouse move.

Comment: Thank you, that's actually what I was looking for. One last question - is it possible to do the same thing, without JS ? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not, you will always need JS to set the position of the description, according to the mouse position. This can only be done with JS.